# python gettext error: Can't convert '__proxy__' object to str implicitly

Tags: python, django, gettext

I'm suddenly getting a weird error in code that was previously working. I recently upgraded to Django 1.9.6 from 1.9.4.

In one of my views, I have:

```
from django.contrib import messages
from django.utils.translation import ugettext_lazy as _

messages.success(request, str( _('A string with a ') +
    '<a target="_blank" href="/preview/' + mymodel.hash + '">' +
    _('link!') + '</a>.'), extra_tags="safehtml"
    )
```

This now gives a `TypeError` on the 2nd last line:

```
Can't convert '__proxy__' object to str implicitly
```

Why? How do I fix this?

#### Edit:

This can be fixed by wrapping the second call to `ugettext_lazy()` in `str()` (i.e. the code becomes `str( _('link!') )`. Doing this allows the view to render fine. My questions is hence now: Why? The entire composite string is already wrapped in `str()`, and as I said, this code worked fine with the previous version of django. Is this a bug?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

`__proxy__` is translation string whose actual translation result isn’t determined until the object is used in a string (i.e. what happens when you use `ugettext_lazy` instead of `ugettext` here).

[Documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/unicode/#translated-strings)

Answer (score 5):

According to the given [Documentation link](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/unicode/#translated-strings):

> Calling str() with the lazy translation as the argument will generate a string in the current locale.